# Push notification to wp8 using javascript (JQuery Request)

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, windows-phone-8, push-notification

So what I am trying to do is pushing notifications to windows 8 application using javascript.

So after checking this website which is the only useful website I found.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202977(v=vs.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202977%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

I understood the following:

1- You need to develop an app that request push notification service URI which will be then shared with a push client service.

(The code for this app needs nothing as you will simply copy it from the link above)

2- You need to send a notification (raw notification) using a push client service

(here appears the problem :) )

The issue that the code is for .NET files which I am not familiar with. I tried to convert the code from the .NET to HTML and .JS where I am going to send ajax request to the given URI.

However this give me a wired error and unfortunately I couldn't find an example of sending notification using .JS

So here is the original code which basically defines a simple form that will send request to the URI. The only difference between this and my code that I am using JQuery Ajax request to send

Original Code

HTML

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="SendRaw.aspx.cs" Inherits="SendRaw.SendRaw" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
   <div>

    <br />
    Enter URI:</div>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxUri" runat="server" Width="666px"></asp:TextBox>
<br />
<br />
Enter Value 1:<br />
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxValue1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<br />
<br />
Enter Value 2:<br />
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxValue2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<asp:Button ID="ButtonSendRaw" runat="server" onclick="ButtonSendRaw_Click" 
    Text="Send Raw Notification" />
<br />
<br />
Response:<br />
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxResponse" runat="server" Height="78px" Width="199px"></asp:TextBox>
</form>
```

C# (.NET)

```
 using System.Net;
 using System.IO;
 using System.Text;
```

C# (.NET)

```
protected void ButtonSendRaw_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            // Get the URI that the Microsoft Push Notification Service returns to the push client when creating a notification channel.
            // Normally, a web service would listen for URIs coming from the web client and maintain a list of URIs to send
            // notifications out to.
            string subscriptionUri = TextBoxUri.Text.ToString();


            HttpWebRequest sendNotificationRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(subscriptionUri);

            // Create an HTTPWebRequest that posts the raw notification to the Microsoft Push Notification Service.
            // HTTP POST is the only method allowed to send the notification.
            sendNotificationRequest.Method = "POST";

            // Create the raw message.
            string rawMessage = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" +
            "<root>" +
                "<Value1>" + TextBoxValue1.Text.ToString() + "<Value1>" +
                "<Value2>" + TextBoxValue2.Text.ToString() + "<Value2>" +
            "</root>";

            // Set the notification payload to send.
            byte[] notificationMessage = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(rawMessage);

            // Set the web request content length.
            sendNotificationRequest.ContentLength = notificationMessage.Length;
            sendNotificationRequest.ContentType = "text/xml";
            sendNotificationRequest.Headers.Add("X-NotificationClass", "3");


            using (Stream requestStream = sendNotificationRequest.GetRequestStream())
            {
                requestStream.Write(notificationMessage, 0, notificationMessage.Length);
            }

            // Send the notification and get the response.
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)sendNotificationRequest.GetResponse();
            string notificationStatus = response.Headers["X-NotificationStatus"];
            string notificationChannelStatus = response.Headers["X-SubscriptionStatus"];
            string deviceConnectionStatus = response.Headers["X-DeviceConnectionStatus"];

            // Display the response from the Microsoft Push Notification Service.  
            // Normally, error handling code would be here. In the real world, because data connections are not always available,
            // notifications may need to be throttled back if the device cannot be reached.
            TextBoxResponse.Text = notificationStatus + " | " + deviceConnectionStatus + " | " + notificationChannelStatus;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            TextBoxResponse.Text = "Exception caught sending update: " + ex.ToString();
        }
```

MY Code

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1">
    <script src="jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>

   <script>
     $(document).ready(function(e) {
        $('#ButtonSendRaw').click(function(){
        console.log("Button Pressed");

        var subscriptionUri = $('#TextBoxUri').val();
        var textbox1 = $('#TextBoxValue1').val();
        var textbox2 = $('#TextBoxValue2').val();

        var rawMessage = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" +
        "<root>" +
            "<Value1>" + textbox1 + "<Value1>" +
            "<Value2>" + textbox2 + "<Value2>" +
        "</root>";
        console.log("Sending Data");
        $.ajax({
            url: subscriptionUri,
            type: "POST",
            data: rawMessage,
            contentType:"text/xml",
            success: function(response) {
               console.log('Sucess');
               console.log("login| Response");
               console.log(response);
              },
             error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    console.log(xhr.status);
                    console.log(thrownError);
            }

            });
        });
    });


</script>
    </head>
    <body>
    Enter URI:<input type="text" ID="TextBoxUri" Width="666px" /> <br />

Enter Value 1: <input type="text" ID="TextBoxValue1" /> <br />

Enter Value 2: <input ID="TextBoxValue2" /> <br />

<button id="ButtonSendRaw">Sending Data</button> <br />

Response: <input ID="TextBoxResponse" Height="78px" Width="199px" /> <br />

  </body>
  </html>
```

The error I am getting from this is:

```
    405 (Method Not Allowed)
```

Where method is set automatically to OPTIONS, although I am sending a POST request

Any suggestions, thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that the `subscriptionuri` value is a URI with a different domain than the website that contains your page with the JQuery code. (e.g. your website is hosted on www.mywebsite.com and the `subscriptionuri` is www.microsoft.com/api/push)

What happens in this scenario is that the browser will attempt to make a Cross Domain Request. There are security considerations to keep in mind when using Cross Domain Requests like Cross-Site Request Forgery or Cross-Site Scripting. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc709423%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more information.

As a rule, Modern browsers will only allow Ajax calls to uris in the same domain as the HTML page. If the uri is in other domain, the browser won't make the direct call. Instead, it will try to make a CORS request.

Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) specification provides a mechanism for web application developers to have a browser-supported mechanism to make XmlHttpRequests to another domain in a secure manner. The CORS mechanism works by adding HTTP headers to cross-domain HTTP requests and responses.  These headers indicate the origin of the request and the server must indicate via headers in the response whether it will serve resources to this origin.  This exchange of headers is what makes CORS a secure mechanism.  The server must support CORS and indicate that the domain of the client making the request is permitted to do so.  The beauty of this mechanism is that it is automatically handled by the browser and web application developers do not need to concern themselves with its details.

There are different flows in CORS like a Simple Request, Preflighted Requests and Credentialed Requests. The request that you are trying to make will fall in to the category of a Preflighted Request because your request body has a Content-Type other than text/plain, application/x-www-form-urlencoded, or multipart/form-data.

```
OPTIONS http://otherdomain.com/some-resource/ HTTP/1.1
Origin: http://mydomain.com
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Access-Control-Request-Headers: X-Foo
```

This will receive the following response from the server (if CORS is enabled on the Server) indicating that the POST operation is allowed

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://mydomain.com
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Foo
Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600
```

Once this response is received, your browser will then make the actual POST.

```
PUT http://otherdomain.com/some-resource/ HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=UTF-8
X-Foo: bar
```

This process ensures among other things that servers that are not CORS-enabled will not process a request that might modify server resources as a side effect prior to the browser disallowing the response because it lacks the proper Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.

In your case since your Server is not CORS enabled you are seeing a OPTIONS call but not the subsequent POST. The easiest way to resolve this is to enable CORS on your server so that the necessary headers can be sent by the server in the response. Hope this helps!

Comment: OK, make sense now, but how I am going to respond with these details from a mobile app ?

Comment: @Abdel-RahmanShoman could you please clarify what you mean by "how am I going to respond with these details from a mobile app?". I don't know the architecture of your application. Could you provide more details on where this HTML page with the ajax call is hosted? You don't need to do anything on your mobile app. You just need to enable CORS on the server where this HTML page is hosted. The addition of the header in the OPTIONS request and the consumption of the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in the response is automatically handled on the client browser. (In the case of Win 8 App, IE 11)

Comment: I just didn't know that these deep details is handled by the browser.
I am getting it know.

The issue now is that I am not able to enable CORS in my code

my code is as following

var invocation = new XMLHttpRequest();
invocation.open('OPTIONS', subscriptionUri, true);
invocation.setRequestHeader('ContentLength', rawMessage.Length);
invocation.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'TEXT/xml');
invocation.setRequestHeader('X-NotificationClass', '3');
invocation.onreadystatechange = handler;
invocation.send(rawMessage);

Comment: @Abdel-RahmanShoman You don't have to explicitly make an OPTIONS request. The code that you originally posted is just fine. You just need to enable CORS on the web server that will host the HTML file you posted in your question. Now having said that, where are you hosting that HTML file you posted in the question? In IIS on a webserver which you can modify? If not, if the HTML page is packaged as part of the mobile app, then you need to write your own Web Service that will act as an intermediary between your app and the server that you are making the AJAX call to.

Comment: Well my code is hosted on Apache server. And to give you clearer vision it is hosted locally using wampserver which basically uses Apache. I used ForwardHQ then to make it online. So basically as I understood from you I just need to make my server allow CORS requests. So I searched online and I found that code 'Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"'. However this made the server go down. By the way I am now using XMLHttpRequest instead of AJAX request, do you thinks this might have an effect ?

Comment: What version of Apache are you using? If it is 7.0.41 and above, it ships with a CORS filter. In which case you need to add this config as shown here http://enable-cors.org/server_tomcat.html Also if your server still crashes, follow this link to get a crash dump and analyze it to see what is going wrong. https://httpd.apache.org/dev/debugging.html#backtrace-win

Comment: Actually I am using wamp so the latest Apache server is 2.2. So I don't know what would be the solution in this case ?